# Como pegar o terceiro valor de um array de objetos

Tags: javascript, node.js

Antes de tudo, **eu já pesquisei sobre**, porém não consegui, pelo menos não de uma maneira simples e que era pra funcionar. Bom tenho uma variável que contém este seguinte array quando dou um console

```
[
 {
  Id: 1,
  User: 'User',
  Password: 'Dn',
  Nome: 'Fhdnd',
  Sobrenome: 'Js'
 } 
]
```

Esse é o array de usuários, porém esse eu quiser pegar só a senha? Não era pra funcionar com `rows[2]` ?
O que eu esperava é que retornasse:

```
[
  {
    Password: 'Dn'
  }
]
```

**Erro:** undefined

O único jeito de eu conseguir alcançar este objetivo é com foreach?

**Obs:** rows é o nome da variável que contém este array

Minha função completa onde estou tentando resolver o problema

```
async function verify(req,res,username,password){
 db.serialize(async function (){                               
  const query = 'SELECT * from Users WHERE User = (?) AND Password = (?)'                                                     
 db.all(query,[username, password],async function(err,rows){    
  try{
   if(rows.length == 1){                                          
    console.time("time1")                                         
    await console.log(rows);                                      
    console.log("Correct user");                                                                                                                
    res.render(__dirname + "/View/Home/index.handlebars");
    rows[2]                                          
    console.timeEnd("time1")                                       
     }
    else{
     console.log("Incorrect user!")}}
    catch{
    console.error("\x1b[31m","Problema com a função de autenticação, erro: \n", err);
    }
  })
})}
```

Aqui é onde quero acessar o índice exatamente, estou chamando a função, só não postei tudo porque é aqui que a função deve mostrar o índice que quero acessar etc ... Só não vou postar o resto porque não estou tendo problema com o restante do meu códico.

Pode ser que eu venha mais de um objeto no array, ou seja vou adicionar mais usuários ao longo do tempo.

Comment: Comentem o que melhorar na pergunta porque me parece bem clara.

Comment: Guilherme, o que você tem é um array com um objeto dentro.

Comment: E como acesso esse indice? Para conseguir exibir só a senha e não todo o array

Comment: Já editei a pergunta augusto

Comment: Atribua aqueles valores a uma variável. E, com base no seu código, pra vc acessar a senha, seria assim: array[0].Password

Comment: Acima, "array" seria o nome da variável. Dá uma olhadinha mais ou menos nesse código: https://codepen.io/Kravin/pen/XWjBwRQ

Comment: Mais esses valores precisam ser dinâmicos porque pode ser que eu exclua algum usuário ou crie um, e vou usar esses valores em outro arquivo então seria meio complicado caso eu tenha 100 usuários saca? Aí eu teria que adicionar 100 vezes esses valores em uma variável.

Comment: Da pra converter o meu "array" pra json pra atingir o meu objetivo não dá?

Comment: Ai realmente teria que ter um foreach. Adicione essa informação na pergunta, que poderá vir vários objetos dentro do array, para que possamos elaborar a resposta certinha.

Comment: Ok, desculpe kkk.

Comment: De boas, Guilhermão.

Comment: Caramba, a galera aqui gosta e meter um downvote em tudo hein?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigão, fiz de três formas aqui para tentar resolver o seu problema. A primeira é para exibir no caso de ser um array com apenas um objeto (que foi o apresentado inicialmente na sua pergunta). As outras duas formas são maneiras distintas de fazer a mesma coisa quando temos uma lista de objetos (um array com vários objetos).

**Código para o caso de ser um array com apenas 1 objeto:**

```js
let usuarios = [{
  Id: 1,
  User: 'User',
  Password: 'Dn',
  Nome: 'Fhdnd',
  Sobrenome: 'Js'
}]

console.log(usuarios[0].Password);
```

**Agora duas formas distintas de percorrer um array de objetos (uma lista de objetos), que é o que parece ser realmente a sua necessidade.**

```js
let usuarios = [{
    Id: 1,
    User: 'User',
    Password: 'Dn',
    Nome: 'Fhdnd',
    Sobrenome: 'Js'
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    User: 'User2',
    Password: 'Cn',
    Nome: 'Alombra',
    Sobrenome: 'PHP'
  },
  {
    Id: 3,
    User: 'User3',
    Password: 'Fn',
    Nome: 'Dinamic',
    Sobrenome: 'Java'
  }
]

/* 1ª forma */
usuarios.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item.Password);
});

console.log('-----');

/* 2ª forma */
for (key in usuarios) {
  console.log(usuarios[key].Password);
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

***OBS:*** Acrescentando essa parte abaixo para passar uma informação adicional sobre uma dúvida que o autor da pergunta demonstrou ter nos comentários. Segue abaixo um exemplo de um Array e manipulação do mesmo.

**Array:**

```js
frutas = ["morango", "laranja", "abacaxi", "banana"];

console.log(frutas[3]); //Acessando elemento de um array
```

- *JavaScript* **NÃO** trabalha com **Array Associativo**, essa forma abaixo não funciona em JavaScript (essa declaração de array funcionaria em PHP por exemplo). **Veja:**

```js
array = ["id" => 1, "nome" => "Bruno", "idade" => 19, "email" => "bruno@email.com"];
console.log(array["nome"]);
```

Acima, vai dar erro. Para se trabalhar com índices associativo, em JS, a melhor forma é trabalhar em forma de objeto. Veja os links abaixo para melhores informações:

[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

[Alternativa para trabalhar com índices Associativos em JS](https://serprogramador.com.br/artigos/topico/javascript/Array-associativo-no-JavaScript)

Comment: Funcionou aqui cara vlw, mas não era pra funcionar também assim `rows[2]` ? Porque estaria pegando o segundo índice do array visto que começa em 0, ou não funciona porque não é um array e sim um array que contém um objeto?

Comment: Fico feliz que deu certo pra vc, Guilherme. Como você disse, dessa forma que vc está citando "rows[2]" não funciona justamente por conter um objeto dentro do array. Você só conseguiria acessar dessa forma que vc citou, se fosse um array normal (array com chave e valor), onde o "2" ali seria a chave. Para acessar um array de objetos vc deve acessar a chave do array (como vc citou), depois acessar o objeto que você quer (por isso o foreach ou outra estrutura de repetição) e por último acessar a propriedade desse objeto que vc quer (Id, User, Password...).

Comment: Vou acrescentar no final da resposta uma representação de um array normal, que seria pego na forma que vc citou.